# PHP Session hijack security

Tags: php, security, session

I've done quite a bit of research on this. Unfortunately none of the information I found was actually useful. I am looking into a specific case of session hijacking, since I've took steps into securing my sessions but this one I cannot figure out.

What I've set up as a security measure is I've taken a browser fingerprint on session start:

```
$_SESSION['fingerprint'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Every time the session is requested I perform the check

```
if($_SESSION['fingerprint'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) // Handle accordingly
```

So with `httpOnly` enabled there isn't really much left for session hijacking except deceiving wifi routers with unsecured connection or any other type of connection listening, where the attacker will be aware of all request headers, so the complexity of the fingerprint doesn't matter at all. If the attacker was to copy all of his victim's request headers, how could I still protect the session?

Comment: http://4techs.org/83/how-to-prevent-session-hijacking/ Might wanna read this.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you are trying to accomplish? Using one param like which browser is running isn't very secure. Actually it's very spoofable.

Comment: @Phillip I've just given that as an example. What difference does it make how many `param`s I'm going to use if an attacker will be aware of all information sent by his victim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. A bunch of HTTP headers, of which cookies are one, is the only thing that's identifying a client. Copying/spoofing all of the headers means impersonating a user. There's nothing more you can do really over a public, anonymous connection. If you need anything more, you'd have to start handing out actual secrets to the client out of band, like client-SSL certificates. This is not really practical though.

In practice, if you protect your connection from men in the middle using SSL connections, this is as practical and secure as it gets.

Comment: I basically agree, though it's worth mentioning that doing an IP identifier check (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) will provide some level of protection because if this data is spoofed packets will not be returned to the correct location - of course IP addresses will often shift mid-session, so it will result in legitimate sessions being terminated, but it is a possible approach if SSL is not possible for some reason. That said, anything that needs to be secure needs to go over SSL.

Comment: Yes, IP checking does not help in the scenario of an attacker at Starbucks, and will have many false positives as well. TCP/IP is a data delivery mechanism, it has nothing to do with authentication, so I'm not even mentioning it. If you're not using SSL, you're doing it wrong to begin with.

Comment: This makes me wonder, how did people use sessions before ssl came along

Comment: @account50 Wrong. They used them wrong. ;-) Google "Firesheep" and what lessons it has thought everyone.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the insight. This is kinda scary actually. Sad to see that SO doesn't always use ssl.. `:D`